# How to check the default output format for xps printer?

Tags: c#, .net, xps, printers

Starting with windows8, XPS Document Writer printer's default file format is "oxps". Default can be changed like it's explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh859698.aspx).

Right now the two possible format are "oxps" and "xps".

Is the a way to get what is the default file format for the XPS Document Writer?

The goal here is to produce some code that return the default format on the computer running the program.

Reason why this is needed: A legacy application isn't compatible with "oxps" file. Therefore, I want to add a warning in that application to tell the user to change the default value to "xps".

Comment: have you tried a google search on `default file format for XPS Document Writer` this is what comes up http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/print-to-xps-document-writer#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @ageonix  this is the link in my question

Comment: Can you just check the windows version and if >7 assume *.oxps? Don't know what you are using this for, but I bet 99% of people don't change their default xps type.

Comment: @MethodMan the goal here is to produce some code that will run in a application. The code will return if default format is "xps" or "oxps" for the current computer running the program.

Comment: @botonomous we have compability issue with oxps, I want to display a warning when windows8+ hasn't changed their default from oxps to xps.

Comment: @AXMIM I see. Can you print a dummy file through the xps printer then check the extension and delete the file?

Comment: @Botonomous, very good idea, but something happened and I don't need  this feature anymore. I let my question here, in case someone ever need it.